# clang vs gcc: function lookup with operator overloads

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

in clang vs gcc trunk (as of March 2020) I find strange behaviour in function lookup (can you please educate me on how this is actually called, does it belong to overload resolution?)
when using operators.

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void blub(std::vector<T> const& i) {
  -i;
  //getsize(i); //this also fails in gcc
}

int operator-(std::vector<int> const& i) {
    return i.size();
}

int getsize(std::vector<int> const& i) {
    return i.size();
}


int main() { blub(std::vector<int>{1}); }
```

When using a function like `getsize` instead of the unary operator, neither gcc nor clang compile, but using operator-, gcc compiles, clang doesn't.
clang is right here, isn't it?

See https://godbolt.org/z/hgGeH3

Comment: i use the godbolt link as is

Comment: GCC bug. Same answer as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793092

Comment: awesome. do you know if there is a bug report already @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

Comment: Couldn't find one.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica If it is the same bug, why does rearranging operator-  make it work on both? https://godbolt.org/z/kEPh8M    and for getsize, https://godbolt.org/z/tMAVJp

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Putting it first makes it available in ordinary lookup. So it should be in the overload set. When it appears second, only ADL can find it, but ADL by definition can't find it.

Comment: the bug report:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94214